# Workflow to sync feature branches

Tags: git, github, workflow, feature-branch

I'm quite new to Git and GitHub, so please help me with this question!

I want to contribute to a github project, so I did the following steps:

- I forked the original repository (the so called `upstream`, right?)
- I git cloned my fork locally (`git clone 'myforkrepo'`)
- I created a new branch to work on a new feature (`git switch -c myfeatureA`)
- I also created a new branch from main to work on another separate feature (`git switch main` and the `git switch -c myfeatureB`)
- I was working on my local branches when I realised that, meanwhile, the upstream main was updated!
- I read about [Syncing a fork - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/syncing-a-fork) and I added the original repo as upstream, switched to my local main and **merged **(`git merge upstream/main`) (Or should I **rebase**?).

Now, my question is: since I need to update all my local branches to the upstream main in order to make pull requests, do I have to merge upstream/main with each local branch? Or do I have to merge the local main with all the branches? And How to update my remote fork?

Comment: before you open PR you need to be aligned with the master branch to avoid conflicts 
do the following to achieve that `git fetch upstream` to get the latest updates from the remote `git rebase upstream/master` to sync your branch with the master `git push -f` to push the changes.

Comment: @odaiwa thanks for your answer. Do the rebase command align also all the feature branches or only the forked main?

Comment: updates the current branch, if you want to update other branches you need to execute the same commands on it.

Answer (score 1):

> do I have to merge upstream/main with each local branch? Or do I have to merge the local main with all the branches?

It depends if you plan to:

- create 2 independent pull requests from the feature branches, or
- create 1 pull request with the work from both feature branches (i.e. merge the feature branches into your `main` and then create a PR from your `main`

If you plan to have to separate PR with 1 feature each then you should integrate the upstream target branch (not always `main`) into your feature branches. It's entirely OK to keep your feature branches in sync with upstream with or without going via your `main`.

The `main` branch is not special per se and if you are not planning to use your `main` branch there is no requirement to keep it in sync with `upstream`. Your `main` is only special if you make it special.

---

It's worth remembering that there is no technical requirement to merge the `target->feature` before you merge `feature->target`; especially if changes are done in different parts of the code. You can just merge `feature->target` and use this merge to see if there are conflicts.

Merging `target->feature` first allows us detecting conflicts early, but also it allows to test the codebase with changes from both branches *before* the actual `feature->target` merge. Sometimes two changes - even if they are in different parts of the code base (i.e. no conflicts) - don't work well together.